# Cant log in to unregistered account

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I created an account with blender stack exchange today, in order to ask a question, but for some reason the account is unregistered. I have other stack exchange accounts so I created another blender account.

It seems as if there are two accounts - one has a green profile picture and the one I use with my other stack exchange accounts is purple.

I cant reply to an answer or upvote it on my question but I can edit the question, through my purple account. I have no access to the green account.

How can I get full access to my account? Or can I merge the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I see what happened.

You already had an SE account:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20782/matt-majic

However, today you came to blender stack exchange, and without logging in you asked a question (that is one of the ways an unregistered account gets created.) thus creating:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20779/mattmajic

Now (I think) you went and "registered" you old SE account with blender, essentially locking you out of your unregistered account. (Normally for unregistered accounts there would be a [register](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42270/278094) link at the top of the page.)

The easiest thing for you to would be to ask for your accounts to be merged.

*check*

So within 24-48 hours you should have only the one [matt majic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20782/matt-majic) account.

Comment: Cheers I think that was what happened. I asked for them to be merged